Decomposing a Fraction Involving Cube Roots for Integration
I had an exam the other day and there was this question to decide whether the following function is improperly integrable from 0 to 1. I wrote a solution for it but now I came to understand it's not correct. but I still can't understand what's wrong with my approach. I read that decomposing like this only works with polynomials but I don't exactly understand why it doesn't work like this
We start by considering the integral:
$$
\int \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{1-x^2}} \, dx.
$$
Attempting a decomposition, we propose:
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{1-x^2}} = \frac{A}{\sqrt[3]{1-x}} + \frac{B}{\sqrt[3]{1+x}}.
$$
Multiplying through by $(\sqrt[3]{1-x^2})$ to clear the denominators, we obtain:
$$
1 = A \sqrt[3]{1+x}  + B \sqrt[3]{1-x} .
$$
Simplifying further, we set (x = 1) to solve for (A) and (B):
$$
A + B \cdot 0 = \frac{1}{2^{1/3}} \implies A = 2^{-1/3}.
$$
Substituting (x = -1):
$$
A \cdot 0 + B = 2^{-1/3} \implies B = 2^{-1/3}.
$$
Now substituting back (A) and (B) into the integral, we have:
$$
= 2^{-1/3} \int \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{1+x}} \, dx + 2^{-1/3} \int \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{1-x}} \, dx.
$$
This simplifies further using substitutions (u = 1+x) for the first integral and (v = 1-x) for the second, resulting in:
$$
= 2^{-1/3} \left( \frac{3}{2} (1+x)^{2/3} - \frac{3}{2} (1-x)^{2/3} \right) \bigg|_0^1.
$$
Finally, evaluating the expression gives:
$$
= 2^{1/3} \cdot \frac{3}{2}.
$$

Btw I think the correct approach is to use the substitution x = sin(t) and then say that since sqrt3 is bounded then the integral is also improperly integrable.

Only polynomials can resolved into partial fractions like this. Radical can’t. It may be evaluated via Beta function.

You can’t assume the existence of A and B and find it.  They don’t exist!

Essentially you would be claiming that
$$1 = \sqrt[3]{\frac{1+x}{2}} + \sqrt[3]{\frac{1-x}{2}}$$
and that is not correct - check for $x=\frac{1}{2}$.

I see, I do understand that it's not correct but I can't see in what step exactly I'm making the error. Is it wrong to assume there exists a decomposition in the first place ? the equation only stands true for x = 1 and x = -1 so maybe there is something wrong with substituting x = 1 and -1 ?

$ \frac{A}{\sqrt[3]{1-x}}+\frac{B}{\sqrt[3]{1+x}} =\frac{A \sqrt[3]{1+x}+B \sqrt[3]{1-x}}{\sqrt[3]{1-x^2}} \not \equiv \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{1-x^2}}$

OP mistakenly assumed the existence of the constant $A$ and $B$ and find them by substitution. There is no such decomposition for radical since we can’t find constants $A$ and $B$ such that
$$A \sqrt[3]{1+x}+B \sqrt[3]{1-x} \not \equiv 1$$
We better evaluate the integral using Beta Function by letting
$x=\sin \theta$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{1-x^2}} d x& =\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{\cos ^2 \theta}} \cos \theta d \theta . \\
& =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos ^{\frac{1}{3}} \theta d \theta \\
& =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin ^{2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-1} \theta \cos ^{2\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)-1} \theta d \theta \\
& =\frac{1}{2} B\left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{2}{3}\right) \\
& =\frac{1}{2} \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{7}{6}\right)} \\
& =\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)}{\frac{1}{6} \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)} \\
& =\frac{3 \sqrt{\pi} \Gamma\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)}\\ &\approx{1.29355}
\end{aligned}
$$

The problem is not the integral but the "decomposition" of the integrand. But your answer is nice. Cheers

There is no constants $A$ and $B$ satisfying $ \frac{A}{\sqrt[3]{1-x}}+\frac{B}{\sqrt[3]{1+x}} =\frac{A\sqrt[3]{1+x}+B \sqrt[3]{1-x}}{\sqrt[3]{1-x^2}} \not \equiv \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{1-x^2}}$

Thanks for the answer, I had done the exact same steps up until cosx^1/3 and then thought that since cosx is bounded in that range then the integral definitely does exist but since I couldn't write it formally and didn't know about Beta function wrote the other approach instead since I didn't see the mistake in it :)

@ Claude Leibovici, thank you for your comment !

"I had an exam the other day and there was this question to decide whether the following function is improperly integrable from 0 to 1."
Evaluating the integral is overreading the problem. To see whether the integral converges, we factor the integrand:
$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{1-x^2}}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{1+x}}×\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{1-x}}$
$=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2-u}}×\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{u}}\ge u^{-1/3}\tag{u=1-x}$
where the inequality follows from $2-u=1+x\ge1$ over the integration range. Then $u^{-1/3}$, with an exponent greater than $-1$, is certainly integrable as $u\to0,x\to1$ and by comparison, the original improper integral converges too.
The definite integral of the comparison function $u^{-1/3}=(1-x)^{-1/3}$ is easily seen to be $3/2=1.5$, and this must be an upper bound of the original integral value. This bound matches with Lai's answer.

You're right I shouldn't have focused on actually finding the answer. nice answer the only other approach I could think of was substituting x = sint but yours is simpler, thanks.
